How to convert AltaCV template to cover letter template?
I am trying to convert the AltaCV template to a cover letter but cannot find the command to change from two columns to one column.
I tried with \onecolumn command but the text is running out of margins.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Why do you not use a letter class like scrlettr2 from KOMA-script or another one?

Thank you for your answer! I can use those templates but there will be no consistency between CV and cover letter. I found the workaround by shifting to the latest AltaCV template and using \usepackage{parcol} with \columnratio{1}.
